# Game Engine animations not working?

Tags: python, animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I've created the animations, and everything is working except when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to sprint. My character plays the animation, after I release keys and play something else like walk it also works, but after that it stops working, and none of the animations will play besides the Idle animation.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: did you already fixed this? please expand the action nodes so i can take a look at it. did you made this 3D model yourself?